# Ability to undo green checks

Tags: support, accepted-answer

My recent question was answered by "Stiv", and I green-checked it. Then I accidentally undid it twice. Is it actually possible to undo green checks, just like votes?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to unaccept an answer. If you(*) hover your mouse over the green checkmark, the mouseover text says something like "You accepted this answer [date] at [time]", followed by "**select to undo**".

(*) This is how it works for me on desktop Firefox. The exact behaviour probably depends on your browser.

Comment: I'm on a mobile-like device and I was not able to "mouse over" things.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat a 'long tap' will do.